# Can I determine how many bytes are in the stdio userspace read buffer associated with a FILE?

Tags: c, linux, stdio, buffering

I'm writing a C program that connects to another machine over a TCP socket and reads newline-delimited text over that TCP connection.

I use `poll` to check whether data is available on the file descriptor associated with the socket, and then I read characters into a buffer until I get a newline. However, to make that character-by-character read efficient, I'm using a stdio `FILE` instead of using the read system call.

When more than one short line of input arrives over the socket quickly, my current approach has a bug. When I start reading characters, `stdio` buffers several lines of data in userspace. Once I've read one line and processed it, I then `poll` the socket file descriptor again to determine whether there is more data to read.

Unfortunately, that `poll` (and `fstat`, and every other method I know to get the number of bytes in a file) don't know about any leftover data that is buffered in userspace as part of the `FILE`. This results in my program blocking on that `poll` when it should be consuming data that has been buffered into userspace.

How can I check how much data is buffered in userspace? The specs specifically tell you not to rely on `setvbuf` for this purpose (the representation format is undefined), so I'm hoping for another option.

Right now, it seems like my best option is to implement my own userspace buffering where I have control over this, but I wanted to check before going down that road.

EDIT:
Some comments did provide a way to test if there is at least one character available by setting the file to be nonblocking and trying to `fgetc`/`fungetc` a single character, but this can't tell you how many bytes are available.

Comment: Closely related: [C| how to check if my input buffer(stdin) is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36428098/364696)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there anyway to peek at the stdin buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993742/is-there-anyway-to-peek-at-the-stdin-buffer)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Those are both closely related! Thanks for the links, I was unable to find them when searching. However, I would like to know specifically if it's possible to portably measure the amount of data buffered in userspace. Making the file nonblocking and doing an `fgetc` followed by an `fungetc` lets me test if there is data, but not check how much. Thanks for you help so far!

Comment: There is definitely no portable way to do it. `setvbuf` and the like can give you access to the buffer portably (by having you allocate the buffer, so you can preserve a pointer to it), but there is no way to determine what parts of the buffer are in use (if any). I'm 99.9% certain you're stuck implementing your own buffering on top of unbuffered I/O if you want that level of information.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Okay, thanks! That's pretty much all I need to hear. If you'd like to reorganize your comment into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.