# Read data from stdio without blocking?

Tags: input, lua, stdio

This question has been haunting me for a while now; is there a way in lua to check if there is any data available on stdio and only then read it?

For example; let's say I have some sort of server that is doing its important stuff that shouldn't be interrupted by a blocking `io.read()` function, but I still want to be able to input commands on the console.

I have tried `io.read(0)` but even that blocks until it gets an `EOF`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to write a custom  pure C-library to check it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26949111/1979882

here an example to how create a C-library for Lua.
http://cs.brynmawr.edu/Courses/cs380/fall2011/luar-topics2.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I don't need this right now, I was just wondering if it was possible to do it in lua (In case I ever need to do it). It's a shame lua doesn't support this by itself =/

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer , lua is very simple language which has got very simple binding with any pure C code (library)

Comment: Yeah I know that, and I appreciate it a lot. But it seems this can be implemented in pure C in a few lines, so I think it could be worth having that in lua. Maybe there is a good reason why it's not though, and I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Because its not possible on `Pure` C. And there already exists many Lua libs which allows do this.