# Use read() C function without stopping code

Tags: c, joystick

I'm trying to read data from a joystick using C code. I have [found online the way to do it](https://gist.github.com/jasonwhite/c5b2048c15993d285130).

This solution seems to work fine but with a problem. When the code reachers the the read() function, it stops and waits until there is change in the joystick device:

```
int read_event(int fd, struct js_event *event)
{
    ssize_t bytes;

    bytes = read(fd, event, sizeof(*event));
    if (bytes == sizeof(*event))
        return 0;
    return -1;
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to make the code run continously and if there is no change in the control device, just return the previous state. So far I did not succeed. Maybe someone can help.

Comment: How have you `open`ed the file descriptor?

Comment: 2 options - [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) or threads.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have opened it with:
        device = "/dev/input/js0";
        js = open(device, O_RDONLY);
as in the original link.

Comment: The function you present looks like it may assume that the file associated with file descriptor `fd` is in non-blocking mode.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, I would prefer the most simple solution without threads or anything. I guess there must be a way of doing it. Is it normal that read() waits?

Comment: @JanusGowda it is normal that `read()` blocks until it can transfer at least one byte, *except* for files that are open in non-blocking mode.  You should be able to open the device in non-blocking mode by including the flag `O_NONBLOCK` in the options bitmask you pass to `open()`.

Comment: @JanusGowda yes, read waits until data is available to be read.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks! This worked great. If you want to put it in an answer I give you the credit.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Thanks for your suggestions !

Comment: I don't know what you need this behavior for, but did you consider to create an event input thread? Like this you could divide the logic for things that you need to be continuously running from that logic where e.g. there may be a block waiting for user-input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are opening the joystick device via `open()` and reading from it via `read()`, I infer that you are coding for a machine that implements a POSIX interface.  For most files, the POSIX `read()` function blocks until it can transfer at least one byte, and that is indeed the behavior you observe.

One way to avoid that is to open the file in non-blocking mode, or to put it in non-blocking mode after opening it but before reading it.  You can do the former by adding the `O_NONBLOCK` flag to your open options:

```
 js = open(device, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
```

That should interact cleanly and favorably with your existing code for reading joystick events.  In the case that no event is available to read, your `read()` call should return immediately, with return value -1, and `errno` set to `EAGAIN`.  Otherwise, it will return the number of bytes transferred.

Note that in general, `read()` is not guaranteed to transfer the full number of bytes you request -- it may successfully read fewer, which you can determine from its return value, and if you don't account for that then you can come to grief.  I don't think you'll see any short reads from the joystick device, however; you should get either a complete event or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the actual API (system call) function, but my idea should work.

Use something like `GetNumberOfInputEvents` (a WinAPI function) to determine whether your read will get stuck (with nothing to read). Then if you judge that it'll get stuck, skip it.

See [Checking the stdin buffer if it's empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948723/) for more information.

Pseudo code:

```
read_event(Event* event){
    if (is_event_buffer_empty())
        // Do nothing because `read` is stuck
    else
        SystemAPI_ReadEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: This is very wrong. Because data might become unavailable after the `is_event_buffer_empy()` - Some other thread reading it.

Comment: The OP is reading via a file descriptor, not a stream, so there is no stream buffer (unless he implements one himself).  Even if there were, the buffer being empty is not the same thing as there being no data available to read.